# Competitor Analysis: Describing Elements

Tags: selling-ux, competitive-analysis

I'm doing some competitor analysis, the bullets points like "Buy 2 scales & save an extra 10%" and "100% moneyback guarantee," what would be a better description to management that just "bullet points" For my analysis documents?

Appreciate the term may be more geared to sales speak, but this is a UX task.

[image]

Comment: Can you be elaborate it further?

Comment: I need to create a UX competitor analysis and I believe there is an actual term for bullet points used in this fashion, other than bullet points.

Comment: @UX I'd say _feature_ as general word (however some of them may be _property_ or _perk_). Maybe there is a domain-specific better term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case

**Unique Selling Proposition (USP)**